# SQL Server query parameter for copy data table to another table form ListView VB.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm using VB.net 2013 and SQL Server Express. I want to copy data from the table that appears in the listview to the temporary table. But I got an error:

> Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem'

What are the correct parameters?

My code looks like this

```
For Each itm As ListViewItem In ListViewMasterBiaya.CheckedItems
        Dim SIMPAN As String = "INSERT INTO TempEntriBiaya WHERE NoKode='" & ListViewMasterBiaya.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0) & "'"
        CMD = New SqlCommand(SIMPAN, CONN)
        CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
End Sub
```

I also include the image as below, when I check it, the data will also copy to the temporary table

[image: IMG1]

Comment: `...SubItems(0).Text`

Comment: Why ignore the itm variable?  CheckedItems and SelectedItems are different collections.

Comment: Use parameters to avoid SQL Injection and formatting errors.

Comment: @LarsTech , So what should I use? what uses the "itm" parameter ?

Comment: `INSERT INTO TempEntriBiaya WHERE NoKode=@item`, then your cmd object would need to supply that information, `CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", itm.SubItems(0).Text)`  Then execute your query.

Comment: Wait, you mean the @item  refers to the table name in the database right?

Comment: No, it's the value you are trying to match in your where clause.  It's not clear "what" you are trying to "insert" into the table.  Generally, you wouldn't have a "where" clause unless you  where doing an Update query.  Insert should look like "INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES (@item1, @item2)`  Those values would be your parameters of "what" you are trying to put into the table.

Comment: Actually the data that I will enter into the temporary table as I explained before. For example, data that when I checked with the checkbox on listview. So, when I checked the data it will appear in the temporary table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments and explanation in-line. Following LarsTech comments.

```vb
Dim SIMPAN As String = "INSERT INTO TempEntriBiaya (Column1Name, Column2Name) Values (@Column1, @Column2);"
'The Using...End Using blocks ensure that your ADO objects are closed and 
'disposed event if there is an error
Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
    'The command and parameters only need to be declared once
    'outside the loop, only the value of the parameters change
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand(SIMPAN, cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Column1", SqlDbType.Int)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Column2", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        'Open the connection at the last possible moment
        cn.Open()
        For Each itm As ListViewItem In ListViewMasterBiaya.CheckedItems
            cmd.Parameters("@Column1").Value = itm.SubItems(0).Text
            cmd.Parameters("@Column2").Value = itm.SubItems(1).Text
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End Using
End Using
```

**EDIT** Use event ListView.ItemChecked

```
Private Sub ListViewMasterBiaya_ItemChecked(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckedEventArgs) Handles ListViewMasterBiaya.ItemChecked
        'e.Item returns the ListViewItem that changed its check
        If e.Item.Checked = True Then
            Dim SIMPAN As String = "INSERT INTO TempEntriBiaya (Column1Name, Column2Name) Values (@Column1, @Column2);"
            'The Using...End Using blocks ensure that your ADO objects are closed and 
            'disposed event if there is an error
            Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand(SIMPAN, cn)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Column1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = e.Item.SubItems(0)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Column2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = e.Item.SubItems(1)
                    'Open the connection at the last possible moment
                    cn.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            End Using
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So, item as a database table column parameter right? if there are 9 columns in my database table, I have to make 9 item or make column1 to column9 parameters for the table data when inserted.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn , I have successfully tried this. but there is a new problem, how about when I selected the 2 data that I checked, but the one that entered the database became 4. Multiples of the amount of data I check. I want only 2 data in the database when I only check 2 data ??

Comment: itm is one of the elements in the ListView.CheckedItems. It represents a row in the ListView. Each row has SubItems that hold the values in each column. You need to get the real names of the columns from the database for the Insert statement. The parameter names (the ones that begin with @) can be anything you want. They must match the parameter names added to the command.

Comment: I don't see how the multiple insert can happen unless you have run the code twice. How is this code being run? What event is it being called from?

Comment: the code run when event ListViewMasterBiaya_ItemChecked. Then, how?

Comment: This event runs when an item it checked or unchecked. So it you begin and check one item. It runs and that one item is entered in the database. Then you check another item. Now 2 items are checked and it runs entering all items in the checked collection and this includes the first item checked. Maybe you need a different event, maybe a button that you click when you are done checking and unchecking. I will add code to my answer showing how to insert from a single item checked.

Comment: I Successfull to use the click buton event. but the data is still stored in the temporary database. Then, how about when I will print again with different data. Even though the previous data was in the database. I want to when unchecked the data will be delete in the temporary database. Are there suggestions from you?

Comment: You could clear the table in the database with `Delete From TempEntriBiaya` or I think Truncate the table. You can just add this at the start of the button click.

Comment: You mean start of the button when the button is clicked like that? or what?