# Invalid attempt to read when no data is present when login access on vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have created a login form in my application. My problem when the login occurred was an error like the title I submitted. my coding as below

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
Call DatabaseConnection()
CMD = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM UserAplikasi WHERE username = '" + txtUsername.Text + "' AND password = '" + txtUsername.Text + "'", CONN)
RD = CMD.ExecuteReader
If RD.HasRows = True Then
ElseIf RD.Item("HakAkses").ToString = "administrator" Then
    Me.Hide()
    FormMenuUtama.MenuStripFormUtama.Items("HOME").Enabled = True
    FormMenuUtama.MenuStripFormUtama.Items("ORDERPLAN").Enabled = True
    FormMenuUtama.MenuStripFormUtama.Items("FINANCE").Enabled = True
    FormMenuUtama.MenuStripFormUtama.Items("BILLING").Enabled = True
    RD.Close()
ElseIf RD.Item("HakAkses").ToString = "orderplan" Then
    Me.Hide()
    FormMenuUtama.MenuStripFormUtama.Items("HOME").Enabled = True
    FormMenuUtama.MenuStripFormUtama.Items("ORDERPLAN").Enabled = True
    FormMenuUtama.MenuStripFormUtama.Items("FINANCE").Enabled = False
    FormMenuUtama.MenuStripFormUtama.Items("BILLING").Enabled = False
    RD.Close()
ElseIf MsgBox("Username atau Password yang anda masukan salah!") Then
    CONN.Close()
End If
```

and when I run out with click button login an error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

and I use the user table with the username, password and HakAkses on database sql server. What's wrong ? please. thanks

Comment: You didn't advance the data reader to the first row of the result set with the `Read` method.

Comment: BTW, and most important, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and also is storing the password in plain text in the DB.

Comment: Learn how to parameterize your queries before [booby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) comes to visit. And also, passwords should NEVER be stored in plain text. They should be salted and hashed.

Comment: What happens when Jimmy O'Conner enters his name? With a password of O'Conner1?  My point being that besides being vulnerable to injection as others have already stated, not parameterizing your queries also poses a usability problem.

Comment: So you [STILL have not learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53655692/sql-server-query-parameter-for-copy-data-table-to-another-table-form-listview-vb) to parameterize your queries. Storing usernames and passwords as plain text is also not a good idea.

Comment: Try using while RD.read instead of If RD.HasRows = True Then.


Also, currently your code logic says that if the table has columns, then you don't do anything; if it doesn't then exit code

Comment: @MrPopo thanks, i have success with your suggestion. thank you so much ..

Comment: no problem, I'll make it an answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using while RD.read instead of If RD.HasRows = True Then. Also, currently your code logic says that if the table has columns, then you don't do anything; if it doesn't then exit code

Answer (score 0):

You have been instructed about why there is not data (lack of .Read) and to use parameters and not to store passwords as plain text in comments. I am posting this as an answer because I needed to add a bit of code to demonstrate.

Your If ... ElseIf statement is not making sense. If your reader has rows then your code falls through to the End If. Is that what you want?

```
    Dim x As Integer = 1
    If x = 1 Then
    ElseIf 1 = 1 Then
        Debug.Print("Second If")
    End If
```